# Customise Asp .Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to asp.net and building application using MVC5. In my application 
-a registered user can create a group 
-a registered user can add friend [by email] and invitation will be send if friend is not existing user
-a registered user can add friend to a group
Now where do I store a friend's profile [non existing user] as its not registered yet and I was thinking of storing in Users able with custom field bool isRegisered so later while accepting invitation and creating account or creating account without invitation link remote validation for email already exist has to be  omitted and updated the user record with given email .
Please help

Comment: Just register the friend and send the email. Make sure the friend account can only be used after email is verified (the invitation is accepted).

Comment: Register the friend like any other user but it won't be active until the email is confirmed if you turn on email confirmation.